# How to make Promise API in a synchronous way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, promise, synchronous

I use [selenium-webdriver](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/) for testing with NodeJS.
I want to make selenium-webdriver API in a synchronous way allowing my tests to be very concise.

[getTitle()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html#getTitle) Schedules a command to retrieve the current page's title. This API return an webdriver.promise.Promise

for example with selenium-webdriver I do

```
driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
   .....
 });

driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
```

How can I do completely synchronous API (make API Promise synchronous?), like this

```
var titleElement = driver.getTitle();
var qElement= driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q'));
qElement.sendKeys('webdriver');
```

**Update (with Benjamin Gruenbaum response) :**

Use yield with Promise.coroutine from [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) API

```
function myBrowser() {

}

myBrowser.prototype.getTitle = Promise.coroutine(function* (driver) {
    var title = yield driver.getTitle(); // yield makes it wait
    console.log('prototype.getTitle: ' + title)
    return title;
});

var driver = createDriver();

driver.get('https://www.google.fr/')
driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    console.log('getTitle: ' + title)
 });

// Use bluebird API
var mb = new myBrowser();
var title = mb.getTitle(driver)
// KO, It' an object Promise, not string title
console.log('main Process: ' + title)
```

Output

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] main Process: [object Promise] 
[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] getTitle: Google
[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] prototype.getTitle: Google
```

Comment: You need to place your whole code in a coroutine, not just the start of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a new version of NodeJS (as in, io.js (node 3.0) or higher) you can use `yield` together with `Promise.coroutine` from bluebird (this can be activated in older versions by running with the `--harmony-generators` flag):

```
Promise.coroutine(function*(){
    var title = yield driver.getTitle(); // yield makes it wait
    yield driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("webdriver");
})();
```

If you're using babel like T.J suggests, you can also use async functions:

```
(async function(){
    let title = await driver.getTitle();
    // ...
})();
```

Comment: Update my post with use bluebird `Promise.coroutine` API but I have some difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless the API makes it possible in some way (see below). If the Selenium API you're using is designed to work asynchronously, you cannot force it to be synchronous. I can't find the documentation for the `getTitle` call you're using, but as it returns a promise, and the value of a promise is only accessible via `then` callbacks (and the promise may not be settled yet when you receive it), and as those callbacks are always called asynchronously (if they're [Promises/A+-compliant](https://promisesaplus.com/)), you're going to have to write code expecting asynchronousness.

You can make that callback more concise, if that's your goal, by using ES6's arrow functions:

```
driver.getTitle().then((title) => {
   // .....
});
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
```

I think for now to use arrow functions with Node, you have to use a transpiler like Babel.

---

Re your update linking the documentation: The API **might** provide a feature that lets you do this: You might be able to use [`wait`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html#wait), but it's hard to tell because the documentation is broken: The example shows `wait` returning the thing that was being waited for (the button):

```
var button = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('foo'), 10000);
button.click();
```

...but the documentation clearly says `wait` returns a promise:

> **Returns**
>
> `webdriver.promise.Promise<T>`
>
> A promise that will be fulfilled with the first truthy value returned by the condition function, or rejected if the condition times out.

If it's the latter that's wrong (which seems likely), then

```
var title = driver.wait(driver.getTitle(), 10000);
```

...would wait up to 10 seconds for the title. Or if your goal isn't really to get the title but instead to get the element with the name `q`, then that's almost exactly like the example for `wait` above:

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.name('q'), 10000).sendKeys('webdriver');
```

Comment: Arrow functions are in v8 now, but most versions of node (and io) aren't running a version that supports them yet (Chrome doesn't either, it's in Canary though).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yup, that's what I thought.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : Update my post with the documentation for the `getTitle` API.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: with `wait` I got `INFO:CONSOLE(0)] main Process: Promise::54 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}`

Comment: @LeMoussel: I've updated the answer with a bit more about `wait`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: My goal is to get the title (in synchronous mode), not promise object

Comment: @LeMoussel: Well, if `wait` doesn't do it, I don't think you can. Too bad about the `wait` docs.